# Getting redux-form values in onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

What's the correct way of getting the values out of a form managed by `redux-form` after every form update? I need to dispatch an action every time the form changes, using the values entered into the form.

My current solution gets the old values out, instead of the ones that were just updated.

```
  onFormChange(e) {
    const { fieldValue1, fieldValue2, fieldValue3 } = this.props.fields;
    console.log(fieldValue1.value, fieldValue2.value, fieldValue3.value);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form onChange={this.onFormChange}>
        // inputs here
      </form>
    );
  }
```

My other solution is this, but I don't know how reliable it is:

```
  onFormChange(e) {
    console.log(e);
    setTimeout(() => {
      const { fieldValue1, fieldValue2, fieldValue3 } = this.props.fields;
      console.log(fieldValue1.value, fieldValue2.value, fieldValue3.value);
    }, 0);
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

With redux-form 6, you can get the values using the [`formValueSelector`](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/FormValueSelector.md/):

```
import { formValueSelector } from 'redux-form';

const selector = formValueSelector('myFormName');

connect(
  state => ({
      values: selector(state, 'fieldValue1', 'fieldValue2', 'fieldValue3');
  })
)(MyFormComponent);
```

Now you can compare the current values, and the previous values in `componentWillReceiveProps`:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const nextValues = nextProps.values; 
    const values = this.props.values;
    // if at least one of the form values changed
    if(Object.keys(nextValues).some((key) => nextValues[key] !== values[key])) {
        console.log(nextProps.values); // do something with values
    }
}
```

Using redux-form up to version 6, you don't have to use the `formValueSelector` as redux-form add the `values` [prop](https://redux-form.com/5.3.3/#/api/props?_k=3ul449) automatically to your decorated form.

Comment: This will cause an infinite loop, because I'm dispatching another action.

Comment: That's why you should check if the values have actually changed, and only if they did dispatch an action. Unless you're changing said values in the dispatched action, and then you'll have an infinite loop.

Comment: The `values` props no longer exists.

Comment: @OriDrori +1 from me for doing that. One thing though, you forgot to add the `select` function which you need to define. It would look something like this: `const selector = formValueSelector('myFormName')`

Comment: For whom it may concern, I want to point out that there is a `getFormValues` selector in version 6+ that will, basically, power you to place all the form's field values in a prop as `this.props.values` used to give them to you in versions previous to 6.

Comment: There is small mistake left. Please change `if(Object.keys(nextValue)` to  `if(Object.keys(nextValues)`